# Use 2D Convolution like "1D Convolution" on images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 256×192 pixel images and search a small and fast cnn as a "pre scanner" to find interesting parts on a image (like 52x52, 32x32 chunks etc), which will be checked with a more complex cnn. The reason for this small cnn is the use within an embedded system with limited resources.

Unfortunately I'm new at this topic, tensorflow and keras. My first idea was to create an net with only one 2D conv which works like an 1d conv. In this case the kernel should have a height of 192 and a width of 1 (maybe later 3).

This is the model which I build on tensorflow 2:

```
# Model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(5, (1, 192), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 192, 3)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The idea is to get one value per row which indicates if something "interesting" can be in this row. Based of this information and the neighbors a bigger part of the image will be cut out and feed into the more complex cnn.

I have prepared normal images with 256x192px and for each image a text file with 256 values (0.0 or 1.0). Each 0/1 represents one row and indicates if something interesting is in this row or not.

This was my naive plan but the training crashes immediately with an error that I dont understand:

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 256 for 'metrics/accuracy/Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [32,256], [32,256,1].`

I think I basic idea/strategy is wrong. I dont unterstand where the 32 comes from. Can someone explain my mistake? And is my idea even feasible?

***Edit:***

As requested the complete, dirty code. If there are some major flaws, please be forgiving. This is my first Python experiment.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

train_images = []
train_labels = []
test_images = []
test_labels = []

# Prepare
dir = os.listdir('images/gt_image')
split = len(dir)*0.2

c = 0

for file in dir:
    c = c + 1

    im = Image.open('images/gt_image/' + file)

    data = im.load()
    image = []

    for x in range(0, im.size[0]):
        row = []
        for y in range(0, im.size[1]):
            row.append([x/255 for x in data[x, y]])
        image.append(row)
    if c <= split:
        test_images.append(image)
    else:
        train_images.append(image)

    file = open('images/gt_labels/' + file + '.txt', 'r')
    label = file.readlines()[0].split(', ')

    if c <= split:
        test_labels.append(label)
    else:
        train_labels.append(label)
print('prepare done')

# Model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(5, (1, 192), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 192, 3)))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

print('compile done')

# Learning
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Comment: Please show your code properly. The error is not related to the code you posted. ----- It seems you need to add an extra dimension to your `y_train` to make it `(whatever, 256, 1)`.

Comment: @DanielMöller done, I added the code

Comment: @Shutterfly Just so you know, 32 comes from the `model.fit()` method, which will default `batch_size` to 32

Comment: You should try changing your `train_labels` shape. If it has shape `(..., 256,1)` change it to `(..., 256)`. If it has shape `(..., 256)` change it to `(..., 256, 1)`. If this doesn't work, try changing the metric to `categorical_accuracy`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `train_labels` as one-hot-encoding with shape `(..., 256, 5)` and `'categorical_crossentropy'`.